# Error when not creating default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors, syntax-error

As a part of my project, I created a parameterized constructor and didn't create a default constructor. When I create an object of that class without passing parameters in 'main()' method and try to access member functions of that class, it gives error. The code works well if I don't create any constructor or when I create just a default constructor. I tried the same using initialization list too, but that didn't work.
The following is the complete code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class worker
{
    public:
    string fname, lname;
    int salary;
    worker(int a)
    {
        salary=a;
    }
    void input()
    {
        cout<<"Enter your first name : ";
        cin>>fname;
        cout<<"Enter your last name : ";
        cin>>lname;
        cout<<"Enter your salary : ";
        cin>>salary;
    }
    void disp()
    {
        cout<<"\nName : "<<fname<<" "<<lname;
        cout<<"\nSalary : "<<salary<<"\n";
    }
    void raise()
    {
        salary +=(0.2*salary);
    }
    ~worker()
    {
        cout<<"\nDestructor called";
    }
};
int main()
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Welcome User!\n";
    //code snippet
    worker tp();//using "worker tp;" also shows error
    tp.input();
    return 0 ;
}
```

Why do I need to create a default constructor, isn't the parametrized enough? And what if I don't want to use that parametrized constructor too?
Kindly guide me as I am completely new to C++

I expected my code to run properly without any default constructor but it didn't work well.

Comment: Any [decent book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or other learning material should have taught you about this.

Comment: *"Why do I need to create a default constructor, isn't the parametrized enough? "*  Yes it is, but you have to *provide* a parameter to use it.

Comment: The problem here isn't actually the constructors, it's that `worker tp();` declares a *function* named `tp`, which take no arguments and returns an `worker` object by value.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you declare your own constructor, C++ does not autogenerate the default constructor. After all, most of the time you want to actually forbid the user the usage of constructors not explicitly specified.
Also, you should initialise the members of worker in the initialiser block (see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)
The following code works, using a default value:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class worker
{
    public:
    string fname, lname;
    int salary;
    worker(int a = 0)
    : fname("")
    , lname("")
    , salary(a)
    {
    }
    void input()
    {
        cout<<"Enter your first name : ";
        cin>>fname;
        cout<<"Enter your last name : ";
        cin>>lname;
        cout<<"Enter your salary : ";
        cin>>salary;
    }
    void disp()
    {
        cout<<"\nName : "<<fname<<" "<<lname;
        cout<<"\nSalary : "<<salary<<"\n";
    }
    void raise()
    {
        salary +=(0.2*salary);
    }
    ~worker()
    {
        cout<<"\nDestructor called";
    }
};
int main()
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Welcome User!\n";
    //code snippet
    worker tp;//using "worker tp;" also shows error
    tp.input();
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't want to work for a zero salary!  :-)